# Options Menu never shows in Fragment

Tags: android, menu, android-fragments

For some reason my Fragment never calls `onCreateOptionsMenu` to inflate my menu, the overflow menu never appears and pressing the menu button in the emulator also does nothing. I've tried using `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` but this also does anothing. 
Any ideas?

Here's my `onCreate, onCreateOptionsMenu and onPrepareOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    setMenuVisibility(true);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); 
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Full Fragment code.

```
public class BackupFragment extends ExpandableListFragment {

    public static final Uri SMS_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    private static final int CONTEXTMENU_IMPORT = 21;
    private static final int CONTEXTMENU_DELETEFILE = 22;
    private static final int CONTEXTMENU_DELETEDAY = 23;
    private static final int UPLOAD_DROPBOX = 24;
    private static final int UPLOAD_DRIVE = 25;
    private static final int DIALOG_LICENSEAGREEMENT = 1;
    private static final int DIALOG_ABOUT = 2;
    public static final int DIALOG_EXPORT = 4;
    public static final String STANDARD_DIRNAME = new StringBuilder(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()).append("/backup/").toString();
    public static File DIR;
    public static final boolean CANHAVEROOT = checkRoot(); 
    public static BackupFragment INSTANCE;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static final int API_LEVEL = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);
    public BackupFilesListAdapter listAdapter;
    private AlertDialog deleteFileDialog;
    private AlertDialog deleteDayDialog;
    private ProgressDialog exportDialog;
    private ProgressDialog importDialog;
    private AlertDialog selectExportsDialog;
    private ExporterInfos exporterInfos;
    private View FragmentView;

    /**
     * Sets up the main content of the application (i.e. loads the list of
     * available backups and generates the context menu).
     */
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.backup_fragment, container, false);
        //registerForContextMenu(FragmentView);
        return FragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        INSTANCE = this;
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Crittercism.init(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "516574be558d6a5f8a00001f");

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        String dirName = preferences.getString(Strings.PREFERENCE_STORAGELOCATION, STANDARD_DIRNAME);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(dirName)) {
            dirName = STANDARD_DIRNAME;
        }
        DIR = new File(dirName);

        listAdapter = new BackupFilesListAdapter(getActivity(), preferences);
        getExpandableListView().setAdapter(listAdapter);
        getExpandableListView().setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo expandableInfo = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

                menu.setHeaderTitle(((TextView) ((ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo).targetView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText());
                if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(expandableInfo.packedPosition) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                    menu.add(0, CONTEXTMENU_IMPORT, Menu.NONE, R.string.button_import);
                    menu.add(0, CONTEXTMENU_DELETEFILE, Menu.NONE, R.string.contextmenu_deletefile);
                    menu.add(0, UPLOAD_DROPBOX, Menu.NONE, R.string.upload_dropbox);
                    menu.add(0, UPLOAD_DRIVE, Menu.NONE, R.string.upload_drive);
                } else {
                    menu.add(0, CONTEXTMENU_DELETEDAY, Menu.NONE, R.string.contextmenu_deletedaydata);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        setMenuVisibility(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), item.toString());
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_about: {
                showDialog(DIALOG_ABOUT);
                break;
            }
            case CONTEXTMENU_DELETEFILE: {
                /* using "showDialog" with a Bundle is only available from api version 8 on, so we cannot directly use this. Lets impose this */

                long packedPosition = ((ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo()).packedPosition;

                if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(packedPosition) != ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                    break;
                }

                final File file = listAdapter.getChild(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition), ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(packedPosition));

                if (deleteFileDialog == null) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                    builder.setTitle(android.R.string.dialog_alert_title);
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // just to enable the button
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setMessage(Strings.EMPTY); // just so that the string is available
                    deleteFileDialog = builder.create();
                }
                deleteFileDialog.show();
                deleteFileDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (!file.exists() || file.delete()) {
                            listAdapter.remove(file);
                        } else {
                            // show error
                        }
                        deleteFileDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                deleteFileDialog.setMessage(String.format(getString(R.string.question_deletefile), file.toString()));
                break;
            }
            case CONTEXTMENU_IMPORT: {
                ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

                long packedPosition = menuInfo.packedPosition;

                if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(packedPosition) != ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                    break;
                }
                if (importDialog == null) {
                    importDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                }
                checkProgressDialog(importDialog);
                new ImportTask(importDialog, listAdapter.getChild(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition), ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(packedPosition)), (Integer) menuInfo.targetView.getTag());
                break;
            }
            case CONTEXTMENU_DELETEDAY: {
                long packedPosition = ((ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo()).packedPosition;

                if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(packedPosition) != ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
                    break;
                }

                final int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition);

                Date date = listAdapter.getGroup(groupPosition);

                if (deleteDayDialog == null) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                    builder.setTitle(android.R.string.dialog_alert_title);
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // just to enable the button
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setMessage(Strings.EMPTY); // just so that the string is available
                    deleteDayDialog = builder.create();
                }
                deleteDayDialog.show();
                deleteDayDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Vector<File> files = listAdapter.getChildren(groupPosition);

                        Vector<File> deletedFiles = new Vector<File>();

                        for (File file : files) {
                            if (!file.exists() || file.delete()) {
                                deletedFiles.add(file);
                            } else {
                                // show error
                            }
                        }
                        listAdapter.remove(deletedFiles);
                        deleteDayDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                deleteDayDialog.setMessage(String.format(getString(R.string.question_deletefile), DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date)));
                break;
            }
            case R.id.menu_exporteverything: {
                if (exportDialog == null) {
                    exportDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                }
                checkProgressDialog(exportDialog);
                checkExportTaskForIncompleteData(new ExportTask(exportDialog, listAdapter, EverythingExporter.ID));
                break;
            }
            case R.id.menu_export: {
                if (selectExportsDialog == null) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_export);

                    exporterInfos = Exporter.getExporterInfos(getActivity());

                    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setItems(exporterInfos.names, new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            if (exportDialog == null) {
                                exportDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                            }
                            checkProgressDialog(exportDialog);
                            checkExportTaskForIncompleteData(new ExportTask(exportDialog, listAdapter, exporterInfos.ids[which]));
                        }
                    });
                    selectExportsDialog = builder.create();
                }
                selectExportsDialog.show();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.menu_settings: {
                break;
            }           
            case UPLOAD_DROPBOX: {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Dropbox.class);

                long packedPosition = ((ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo()).packedPosition;

                final File file = listAdapter.getChild(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition), ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(packedPosition));
                i.putExtra("file", file.toString());
                i.putExtra("path", file.getName());

                startActivity(i);
                break;
            }
            case UPLOAD_DRIVE: {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DriveAuth.class);

                long packedPosition = ((ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo()).packedPosition;

                final File file = listAdapter.getChild(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition), ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(packedPosition));
                i.putExtra("file", file.toString());
                i.putExtra("path", file.getName());

                startActivity(i);
            }

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the exporter that is attached to the given ExportTask may
     * produce incomplete data and shows a warning if this is the case and
     * if the user wants to get notified. Note that the standard setting is
     * to show the warning.
     * The user may also cancel the warning dialog which results in the
     * export to be not performed.
     *
     * @param exportTask task whose exporter is checked w.r.t. incomplete
     *                   exports
     */
    private void checkExportTaskForIncompleteData(final ExportTask exportTask) {
        Exporter exporter = exportTask.getExporter();

        if (!PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getBoolean(Strings.PREFERENCE_HIDEDATAWARNINGS, false) && exporter.maybeIncomplete()) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            builder.setTitle(android.R.string.dialog_alert_title);
            builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.warning_incompletedata_export, exporter.getIncompleteDataNames(getActivity())));
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    exportTask.execute();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.show();
        } else {
            exportTask.execute();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Here, the given progress dialog will be reset.
     *
     * @param dialog progress dialog to be reset
     */
    private void checkProgressDialog(ProgressDialog dialog) {
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        dialog.setMax(100);
        dialog.setMessage(Strings.EMPTY); // we just have to set some non-null value to enable the title
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        if (importDialog == null) {
            importDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        }
        checkProgressDialog(importDialog);
        new ImportTask(importDialog, listAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition), (Integer) v.getTag());

        return true;
    } 


    protected void showDialog(int id) {
        if (id == DIALOG_LICENSEAGREEMENT) {
            AlertDialogFragment myDialogFragment = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance();
            myDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialogFragment");
        }
    } 



    /**
     * In order to perform certain backups (such as the wifi settings), we
     * need root to access the corresponding configuration files.
     *
     * @return true if <i>root</i> access can be obtained, <i>false</i>
     *         otherwise
     */
    private static boolean checkRoot() {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ls -l /system/bin/su /system/xbin/su");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line = reader.readLine();

            reader.close();
            process.destroy();

            return line != null && line.length() > 9 && line.charAt(9) == 'x';
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: post your `Activity` code too.

Comment: Do you use an ActionBar?

Comment: Did your device contain hard button or you enabled the title bar for your application? If no title bar or no hard button than it will no create option menu, it will create option for your application if title bar or hard button available

Comment: I'm using an ActionBar yes, and that is displaying fine. My device doesn't have a hard button but the emulator has an emulated one and pressing that also doesn't show it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably inflating stuff on the activity and not calling super.

If you're inflating any menu items on any other fragment or in the activity you should also call `super.onCrea ....` on them.

Another option for common menu problems is, if you're using actionbar sherlock, you should extend the SherlockFragment in order to use the menu.

Comment: I don't inflate menu items anywhere else in my activity but I do add to a context menu in my `onActivityCreated` method.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to ABS instead of the Support library seems to have fixed things, it may have been due to conflicts with the SlidingMenu library I am using.